# Negative Intersection and Vanishing global section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic surface, $H$ be a very ample divisor. Suppose $C\in|H|$, such that $\deg_C(D)=DC<0$, with some divisor $D$.

**Q**: Why $h^0(C,D|_C)=0$?

Comment: Isn't it just the fact that for any divisor $D$ with negative degree on a curve, $h^0(C,D)=0$ ? (Because a rational function can't have more zeros than it has poles)